# why isn't my element:contains(variable) work when using variable instead of string? jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, contain

I have a code to get the value of option element and when a button is clicked, it'll find where that value exist in the page so I can add more things into that table / container.

Somehow if I store the value into a variable, it doesn't work.  If I type in the string directly into `$("blah:contains('blabhblah')"` it will work. why?

My example here in html

```
        <div class="shipping-time-city">
            <label>City: </label>
            <select>
                <option value='bby'>Burnaby (本拿比)</option>
                <option value='van'>Vancouver (温哥华)</option>
                <option value='rmd'>Coquitlam (高贵林)</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

other places in the body I have something like

`<caption>Coquitlam (高贵林)</caption>`
`<caption>Burnaby (本拿比)</caption>`
`<caption>Vancouver (温哥华)</caption>`

so in jquery I used click function and this is what I have inside click function

```
var getCity = $( ".shipping-time-city option:selected" ).text();
($("caption:contains(getCity)").text('bye')  //just for testing
```

the above wouldn't work but if I do it like this

```
($("caption:contains('Burnaby (本拿比)')").text('bye')
```

it will work, but I tried `console.log(getCity)` which gives me the output of `Burnaby (本拿比)`

can someone give me a hand on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is `caption`?

Comment: @guradio element tag

Comment: then your problem is with string concat you see getcity is get as string not variable change to `"+getCity+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since getCity is a variable, would it not be:

```
($("caption:contains('" + getCity + "')").text("bye");
```

Comment: ah! omg I didn't try that yet stupid me, let me try it later tonight

Comment: omg thanks it does work, really felt like asking some easy stupid question again. thx thx

Comment: yay :)) - happy coding!